# Windows PowerShell to install NativeScript on Windows 10

Tags: powershell, nativescript

I try to install NativeScript on Windows 10 from Admin PowerShell console.

https://docs.nativescript.org/start/ns-setup-win

I type this command and obtain the following error:

```
@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://nativescript.org/setup/win-avd'))"
```

[image: 10]

Comment: Could you translate the error to English? This will make it easier to help you.

Comment: I read the document you pasted. Just run this in CMD not powershell. IF you were going to run this in powershell all you needed to do was `(new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://nativescript.org/setup/win-avd')`

Comment: Thanks @ArcSet ! I don't know read :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running the command from PowerShell when you need to run it from CMD command prompt.

Run this from CMD:

```
@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://nativescript.org/setup/win-avd'))"
```

Here, `@powershell` means "don't echo the command and run powershell.exe".  It means something completely different in PowerShell itself, where `@powershell` means "search the path and execute a program with the literal name `@powershell` before the extension" or "use the variable `$powershell` as a splat variable" depending on your PowerShell version.

If you're running it in Powershell, you'll need to run just:

```
iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://nativescript.org/setup/win-avd'))
```

As always, be *extremely* careful about running these commands that download arbitrary code and execute it immediately.